# Converting numpy array to list returns type numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to convert numpy array to list, and I noticed that it still returns a ndarray.
I tested it with a simple example and it still returns ndarray:

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
a
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
type(a)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
a.tolist()
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
type(a)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

The second result does look like a list, however the type has not changed. Why is this happening and what is the way to convert it to list?

Comment: `type(a)` -> `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`, but `type(a.tolist())` -> `<class 'list'>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`tolist()` method doesn't work in-place. You need to reassign the result:

```
In [5]: a = a.tolist()

In [6]: type(a)
Out[6]: list
```

Comment: Thank you! I should have checked that as well.